# Fetch videos from a Sony Handycam DCR-DVD101 to Linux

Tags: linux, usb, usb-storage

I've got a Sony Handycam DCR-DVD101. When I plug connect the USB cable to my laptop (Ubuntu 10) it doesn't mount any storage device.

If I run `usb-devices`, I see:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=054c ProdID=00c1 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=SONY
S:  Product=Storage Device
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=05 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

The driver says usb-storage, but I'm not sure how to get the device mounted. Is there a way to make this work?

**Update**: checking dmesg, I see:

```
[259072.576559] usb 2-1.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[259072.687200] usb 2-1.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[259072.836188] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[259072.836476] scsi5 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[259072.836632] usb-storage: device found at 6
[259072.836636] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[259072.836660] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[259072.836666] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[259077.830410] usb-storage: device scan complete
[259077.832343] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            SONY     DDX-A1010        R1.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[259077.888167] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x pop-up
[259077.888446] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[259077.888593] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[259080.002079] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] Unhandled sense code
[259080.002085] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[259080.002091] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] Sense Key : Blank Check [current] 
[259080.002097] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[259080.002104] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[259080.002117] end_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 0
[259080.002123] Buffer I/O error on device sr1, logical block 0
[259080.002128] Buffer I/O error on device sr1, logical block 1
```

Those I/O errors don't look good, is there any hope?

Comment: Does the `/dev/sr1` device node show up? What happens when you attempt to mount it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recipe for RHEL/CentOS (Ubuntians beware.)

To show device nodes assigned to USB storage devices

```
$ dmesg | grep -i "SCSI dev" 
SCSI device sdb: 7716864 512-byte hdwr sectors (3951 MB)
```

To see the device node for a FAT32 parttition

```
$ fdisk -l -u /dev/sdb
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192     7716863     3854336    b  W95 FAT32
```

To mount the drive

```
$ mkdir /mnt/flash
$ mount -t vfat -o uid=myname,gid=myname /dev/sdb1 /mnt/flash
```

Add extra su|sudo to taste.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is shown here:

```
[259080.002091] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] Sense Key : Blank Check [current]
```

Several things can cause this.

Most likely, you either have no DVD or a blank DVD in the camcorder at the time you plugged it into your computer. Try inserting a DVD on which some video has been recorded.

It could also be that the camcorder doesn't like the brand of DVDs you've been using, or that the lens is dirty and needs to be cleaned.